# Redirect IPv6 on apache with passenger error URL truncated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, redirect, passenger

I have a RoR app running with passenger on Apache, on a Red Hat 7 server, already running but in some redirects with the rails app, ie. the login page, seems that the URL is truncated because is an IPv6, the app doesn't crash, but with different browser shows an error, with firefox shows an error that says "Error, damaged content" but watching the request I can see that the redirect shows the URL truncated.

[image]

on "Location: "http://[fc00/login" " should be "http://[fc00:ces::13]/login 
and some other redirect crash like this.
How can I escape the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved this by adding a domain on my hosts file, it seems that apache or passenger wasn't redirecting because of the Ipv6, adding the domain while developing solved the issue, the final domain is not ready, so while testing use a domain on the hosts file pointing to the ipv6 of the server.